# Using string from Cursor to get drawable to ImageView

Tags: android, resources, decode, identifier

I have a database with string names and string filenames that I am using to dynamically create a page. On the previous page based on the button selected the cursor returns the specific entry needed, and then that is used to find and display the corresponding image. I've been trying to mish-mash code from different places, but nothing seems to be working. It currently looks like this:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
Bitmap bmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
getResources().getIdentifier(c.getString(4), "drawable", getPackageName()));
iv.setImageBitmap(bmap);
```

For debugging purposes I've had the cursor getString(4) toasted and it comes out correctly as "al_0" or what it should be, and there is a file in the "drawable" folder in res named "al_0.jpg".

I've tried various combinations of concatenating the packagename and drawable folder location directly with the image name, and putting null in the other variable positions. Each time either I get a crash with a reference to the decodeResource line or that the "No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000."

Any help would be appreciated, and if more specifics are needed I can try to provide them.

Update: So it seems like something else is wrong, using even the following I get a crash:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.al_0);
```

and R.drawable.al_0 is definitely a correct resource in drawable-mdpi (I moved it by a suggestion from Lint).

Comment: Your approach seems fine at a glance, provided you obey the resource naming convention `[a-z0-9_.]` - though if you don't, you'll get build errors. Have you made absolutely sure that there's a drawable entry with name e.g. `al_0` being generated in your `R.java`? Especially if you're using library projects (potentially multiple package names and `R` files) you might want to double check this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've double and triple checked that the line does exist in the R.java file:
`public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int al_0=0x7f020000;`

Comment: can you use log and print out the output of getResources().getIdentifier(c.getString(4), "drawable", getPackageName()) ?

Comment: Went ahead and did that, I am definitely getting the decimal integer value of the hex "0x7020000." I tried to do it again using an integer 'imageresource' variable like `decodeResource(this.getResources(),imageresource)` but I'm still getting the same crash on the decoding. Could it be the decimal/hex conversion issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do.

Store the filename in the format `com.example.appname:drawable/filename` Notice the colon between appname and drawable.

Then after I pull that string from the database I use this, where `imageString` is the string from the cursor.

```
imageResource = ClassName.this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageString, null, null);
imageView.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

Comment: I guess I could do this, but what I don't understand is how this is any different from what I was doing before. It seems like its just changing where I am concatenating the strings, which doesn't seem to make sense, and like I said I've tried various other combinations. I'll give this a shot, as it won't be too much of a hassle, but if there was a simpler solution where I did not have to hard code the packagename into the database that'd be ideal.

Comment: You could add the package name in code and just have `filename` in the database and do something like `String imageString = "com.example.appname:drawable/" + stringFromCursor`.

Comment: So I've tried all of these possibilities and it seems like the issue is with `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` in the android package. I tried both using `BitmapFactory` directly and `setImageBitmap` and `setImageResource` and both traces return the traceroute to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out everything was completely fine, my images were just to large. Using `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` I was able to get everything working fine. Thanks for the helpful debugging tips, I apologize for the mishap.

Update: I also needed to bmap.recycle() as these views were being dynamically created, and they were causing memory errors after a few were opened. Both worked out as being optimal solutions to the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it. You way want to accept your answer as the correct one so it doesn't show as an open question.